# android app failling on launch after adding admob

Tags: java, android, admob

I added admob into my app and it's not able to launch it.. everythime it shows "Unfortunately, app has stopped"

Here is my code in layout:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
              android:id="@+id/adView"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              ads:adUnitId="- MY ID -"
              ads:adSize="BANNER"
              ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
```

here is implementation in Activity

```
private AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(new Bundle());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And this is what i added into manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<meta-data android:value="true" android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS" />
```

Did I do something wrong? Or is there something what I should do? Thanks !

Comment: Where is your logcat and why are you loading the adview twice via xml and code, ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" loads the ad right away, you dont need to implement again in code

Comment: okey, I deleted loading in code... and what is logcat? I didnt find anything like that.

Comment: The logs that you see in console.what do you see in console when your app crashes?